# How to display a Google Map of Mars?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know it's possible to display a [Google Map of the Moon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image) using the ImageMapType class in the Google Maps JavaScript API (v3.22 - Release). But is there a way to show a Google Map of Mars? I don't know if it's possible neither I'm not able to find an example.

I've seen there was [some kind of support](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/sky_mars_moon?hl=en) for the Google Earth API, but it's deprecated and it's going to be shut down early in 2016.

Comment: Do you have access to the imagery?

Comment: related link: [Mapping Mars with Open Planetary Data](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/2012-08-26-mapping-mars/)

Comment: Example: [Google Mars](http://www.google.com/mars/) (not hard to find)